# Rails Internationalization, html tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm having some problems having html tags correctly loaded in my Rails 3.2 app, and have no clue why. I managed to get it working for one flash message, but I am not managing to do it with a confirmation message.

Any ideas ?

My pt.yml file extract :

```
 buttons:
    accept_terms: "Aceito os termos e condições"
    save: "Gravar"
    delete: "Apagar"
    add_new_receipt: "+"
    add_receipt_label: "Clique para adicionar novo recibo"
    download_all_html: "Tem a certeza que deseja descarregar todos os ficheiros correspondentes à pesquisa? <br />
    Esta operação pode demorar algum tempo, dependendo do número de ficheiros e da sua ligação à Internet "
```

my view code:

```
<%= link_to (t :download_all, scope: "pages.home.customers"), user_download_all_path(user_id:current_user.id, is_retailer: params[:controller]=='suppliers' ? true : false), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary", confirm: t(:download_all_html, scope: "buttons") %>
```

In the end, My confirmation message shows the `<br />` as is....

I believe I am following rails [guidelines](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-safe-html-translations) here, so any help would be appreciated to figure this one out.

**Edit**

I had already tried html_safe.

I have one other example that is working :

```
tags:
      error_message_html: "O número %{message} ou não existe ou já foi mapeado.<br />
      Por favor verifique que o número corresponde à empresa seleccionada "
```

and I invoke it inside a controller :

```
flash[:error] = t :error_message_html, scope: "forms.tags", message: params[:tag][:number]
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails will escape the html contained in the translation

You can allow the html to be used with `html_safe`

```
<%= link_to (t :download_all, scope: "pages.home.customers").html_safe, user_download_all_path(user_id:current_user.id, is_retailer: params[:controller]=='suppliers' ? true : false), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary", confirm: t(:download_all_html, scope: "buttons") %>
```

Comment: Hi @Intrepidd, I actually had tried that before.. right now I added `<%= link_to (t :download_all, scope: "pages.home.customers").html_safe, user_download_all_path(user_id:current_user.id, is_retailer: params[:controller]=='retailers' ? true : false), method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary", confirm: (t :download_all_confirmation_html, scope: :buttons).html_safe`, but still keep getting the <br /> within my message... I'm running on a development windows machine, if that may influence somehow